# How do I create a prepared insert statement in Sequel?

Tags: ruby, mysql2, sequel

I am attempting to create a prepared `insert` statement in Sequel and I am as far as

```
db[:registration].prepare(:insert)
=> <Sequel::Mysql2::Dataset/PreparedStatement "INSERT INTO `registration` () VALUES ()">
```

How do I create a statement that is something like the following:

```
INSERT INTO `registration` (`name`, `email`) VALUES (?, ?)
```

The documentation is a little bit obtuse and I can't find any examples online.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Figured this out looking at their rspecs:

```
statement = db[:registration].prepare(:insert, :prepared_statement_name, :email => :$email, :name => :$name)
statement.call(:name => "foo", :email => "foo@bar.com")
```

**NOTE**

The keys that are passed to `.call` correspond to the values passed in the hash in `prepare`. So this would work too:

```
statement = db[:registration].prepare(:insert, :prepared_statement_name, :email => :$e, :name => :$n)
statement.call(:n => "foo", :e => "foo@bar.com")
```

Comment: Not the most intuitive way of doing prepared statements, ($ signs are just awkward) and most implementations use sequence to match columns and values up. However, here is the full documentation: http://sequel.jeremyevans.net/rdoc/files/doc/prepared_statements_rdoc.html

Answer (score 1):

```
ds = db[
         "INSERT INTO `registration` (`name`, `email`) VALUES (?, ?)", 
         name, email
     ]
ds.call(:insert)
```