# Update database with single quote fails Ruby on Rails

Tags: mysql, ruby

I need to update one database table with the data of another using ruby scipt. If there is a single quote in the field it throws the error. How to avoid it?

In the following example it fails to insert nish's.

```
A_db: products table info:
     id    text
    ----------------
      1    hashh
      2    nish's
```

```ruby
A_db = Mysql2::Client.new(
           :host => "xxx", 
           :username => "xxx",
           :database => "xxx",
           :password => "xxx")
B_db = Mysql2::Client.new(
           :host => "zzz", 
           :username => "xxx",
           :database => "xxx",
           :password => "xxx")

Adata = A_db.query("select * from products;")
Adata.each do |d|
   id= d['id']
   B_db.query("insert ignore into products(id, text) values('#{id}', '#{d['text']}')")
end
```

Comment: Yes, you need to escape the value of `d['text']`, since it might contain a single quote (or worse: code to do SQL injection).

Comment: Did you consider doing this in plain `SQL`? It seems like there is no need for Ruby at all. SQL would be much faster than loading everything into memory.

Comment: @Wukerplank  How to escape it in this sentence?

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [`Mysql2::Client.escape` method](http://www.rubydoc.info/github/brianmario/mysql2/Mysql2%2FClient.escape).

But don't. Instead, use prepared statements. Prepared statements are the best way to both escape your values and protect yourself from SQL injection attacks.

The Mysql2 README has an example of prepared statements [in its Usage section](https://github.com/brianmario/mysql2/blob/40cae130b6d183dd4a1911dbc41791b04f1930aa/README.md#usage), which I'll duplicate here for posterity:

> Prepared statements are supported, as well. In a prepared statement,
>   use a `?` in place of each value and then execute the statement to
>   retrieve a result set. Pass your arguments to the execute method in
>   the same number and order as the question marks in the statement.
>
> ```
> statement = @client.prepare("SELECT * FROM users WHERE login_count = ?")
> result1 = statement.execute(1)
> result2 = statement.execute(2)
>
> statement = @client.prepare("SELECT * FROM users WHERE last_login >= ? AND location LIKE ?")
> result = statement.execute(1, "CA")
> ```

And so, your query would look something like this:

```
statement = B_db.prepare("INSERT IGNORE INTO products (id, text) VALUES (?, ?)")
statement.execute(d["id"], d["text"])
```

Answer (score 0):

You are more or less opening up for SQL injection here. That is not optimal so you should protect yourself from that any way. The problem is that your string is considered a part of your sql statement. There are a few ways to avoid that. One way is to use prepared statements.

In this question they discuss a few options for using prepared statements in ruby [How do I create a prepared insert statement in Sequel?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18797947/how-do-i-create-a-prepared-insert-statement-in-sequel)

Comment: Not more or less. This is definitely an SQL injection :)